# Heap corruption occurs when getting system time.

Tags: c, windows

Here is my code. The error occurs when running to the fourth line "tstruct" part.

```
time_t     now = time(0);
struct tm  tstruct;
char       buf[80];
tstruct = *localtime(&now);
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d.%X", &tstruct);
```

Windows has triggered a breakpoint in abc.exe. This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in abc.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded. This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while abc.exe has focus. The output window may have more diagnostic information.

tidtable.c

```
 _CRTIMP PFLS_GETVALUE_FUNCTION __cdecl __set_flsgetvalue()
  {
  #ifdef _M_IX86
  PFLS_GETVALUE_FUNCTION flsGetValue = FLS_GETVALUE;
  if (!flsGetValue)
  {
    flsGetValue = DecodePointer(gpFlsGetValue);
     TlsSetValue(__getvalueindex, flsGetValue);
  }
```

Comment: What is the relevance of `tidtable.c` to the problem?  The normal usage is `time_t now = time(0); struct tm *tp = localtime(&now); char buf[80]; strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d", tp);`, but what you've written should work OK.  Maybe you should investigate [`localtime_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye.aspx)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler When I debug, it stops at this line  `tstruct = *localtime(&now);`  And tidtable.c comes out and there is a green arrow pointing `PFLS_GETVALUE_FUNCTION flsGetValue = FLS_GETVALUE;` and saying that **this is the next statement to execute when this thread returns from the current function**

Comment: Frankly, I am not sure what's up. Is the time code in `tidtable.c`?  Are you playing with threads?  The time functions are not thread-safe, AFAIK.  Depose anything change if you do as I suggested is more usual?  I suspect that the cause of the trouble is elsewhere, but I have no proof of that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I change

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I changed the order of these lines of code. I moved them to the front of other parts of the function.  And now it works! I don't know why.

Comment: That strongly suggests that the other parts of the function are abusing memory somehow, and if not that, some other part of your code is.  Have you tried [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)? Are you sure you are not exceeding the stack limits for your threads?